# How to calculate the standard error of the differences of means in R?

Tags: r, plyr, standard-error

The data below shows how vowel durations (vdur) vary by final consonant (finalC). 
A total of 15 participants produced one item two times. Using `ddply` function, I got the by-subject means of vowel duration for each item.

```
vdur = read.delim("Ldurations.txt")
Lvdur = vdur[vdur$environment == "A",]
bySubjmean <- ddply(Lvdur, c("task", "environment", "subject", "item", "finalC", "neutralizedC"), summarize, "bySubj" = mean(vdur), "SD"=sd(vdur))


> bySubjmean
task environment subject   item finalC neutralizedC bySubj          SD
1      A           A     T01     ip      p            p  90.00  5.37401154
2      A           A     T01    iph     ph            p  66.05  9.26309883
3      A           A     T01    kap      p            p  73.80  0.98994949
4      A           A     T01   kaph     ph            p  48.10 15.98061325
5      A           A     T01   keot      t            t  79.85  1.20208153
6      A           A     T01  keoth     th            t  50.65  6.43467171
7      A           A     T01    mit      t            t  87.45  5.44472222
8      A           A     T01   mith     th            t  69.55  0.91923882
9      A           A     T01    muk      k            k  60.25  0.21213203
10     A           A     T01   mukk     kk            k  42.65  6.01040764 
11     A           A     T01    nak      k            k 122.10  4.80832611
12     A           A     T01   nakk     kk            k  66.00  0.98994949
```

I'd like to calculate the standard error of mean vdur differences between finalC "p" and "ph" (and between "t" and "th" and "k" and "kk", respectively).

Although I could easily calculate the mean difference between p and ph (68.42250 - 50.04083 =18.42...) and its SE using ddply(), I was not able to figure out how to calcualte the SE of this mean difference using R codes.

```
> grandmean <- ddply(bySubjmean, c("task", "environment", "finalC", "neutralizedC"),
   summarize, "grandMean" = mean(bySubj),"SE"=sd(bySubj)/sqrt(length(bySubj)))
> grandmean
   task environment finalC neutralizedC grandMean       SE
1     A           A      k            k  84.34133 2.844009
2     A           A     kk            k  56.51800 1.979809
3     A           A      p            p  68.42250 2.751806
4     A           A     ph            p  50.04083 2.208335
5     A           A      t            t  72.06778 1.975539
6     A           A     th            t  53.19889 1.819296
```

Comment: Is that a paired design?

Comment: No, it is not (although it looks like yes). In regression analysis, coda type was a predictor.

Comment: Well, then this is an error propagation exercise.

Comment: Actually all items were in pair in a way that only final consonant differs. However, what I am looking at is whether two items in a pair vary in vowel duration depeding on final consonant. This is why coda type is a variable.

Comment: Those are domain specific details, which are not really of interest. Write down how you would calculate the standard errors from your example data by hand and then we can show you how to do it with R.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I modified my quesiton to add more information about data. Now can you see it?

Comment: @someday Yes, I can see it. Thanks for the response.  Just a doubt `summarySE` seems to from some package?

Comment: It's from the "bear" package.

Comment: @Roland I refined my question. Hope this helps...

Comment: @akrun I found that ddply() for getting grandmean actually produces the same results as summarySE does.

Comment: @someday You could use `dplyr` if the dataset is really big.  `bySubjmean %>% group_by(task, environment, finalC, neutralizedC) %>% summarise(grandMean=mean(bySubj), SE=sd(bySubj)/sqrt(length(bySubj)))`.  Please look online for the formula for calculation of SE of difference of means.  For example http://vassarstats.net/dist2.html

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's still not clear to me how you intend to calculate the SEs of the mean differences. If it's not a paired design you would need to do error propagation, i.e., SE(mean1-mean2) = sqrt(SE(mean1)^2+SE(mean2)^2). If the design is paired you could calculate the differences between the pairs and calculate the SE from those.

Comment: @akrun It's much quicker than using ddply() or summarSE()! Thanks for sharing the link, too!

Comment: @Roland Thanks for the formula! (I'd better doublecheck my understanding about paired design:() Now I have to code it in R, which is actually the gist of my question..